# Every gps request seems to try to find new satellite. How to overwrite this?

Tags: android, gps

My application get current GPS coordinates every 10 seconds in service.
But I notice that every 10 seconds GPS icon hides and then shows itself again(I think GPS tries to find a new satellite on every request. )

**How to make all request to one satellite?**

My code :

```
 if (isGPSEnabled) {
               // if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("myLogs", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: This code portion runs every 10 seconds or only once?

Comment: @ramaral, Every 10 seconds

Comment: Please post the entire code of the service

Comment: If you're accessing the location once every 10 seconds, Android will show the icon that indicates location being accessed every 10 seconds. Isn't that common sense?